# How to make an R plot of SNPs on the x-axis and beliefs on the y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly

How to make an R plot of SNPs on the x-axis and beliefs on the y-axis? Maybe a jitter plot? Or an interactive plotly? If I were using Python, hash table would be the simplest data structure for this. But it looks like R doesn't support such a data structure easily?

[image]

`dput` result:

```
> dput(head(bel_bpa_df))
structure(list(SNPs = list(c("rs12117661 ", " rs11588151 ", " rs34232196 ", 
" rs4500361 ", " rs4927191 ", " rs200159426 ", " rs187607506 ", 
" rs12748266 ", " rs11206510 ", " rs34900073 ", " rs55958021 ", 
" rs12404395 ", " rs613855 ", " rs624612 ", " rs625619 ", " rs479910"
), c("rs12117661 ", " rs11588151 ", " rs34232196 ", " rs3976734 ", 
" rs4500361 ", " rs4927191 ", " rs200159426 ", " rs187607506 ", 
" rs12748266 ", " rs11206510 ", " rs34900073 ", " rs2495491 ", 
" rs2479415 ", " rs2495489 ", " rs55958021 ", " rs12404395 ", 
" rs2479404 ", " rs2479409 ", " rs613855 ", " rs624612 ", " rs625619 ", 
" rs479910"), c("rs12117661 ", " rs11588151 ", " rs34232196 ", 
" rs4500361 ", " rs4927191 ", " rs200159426 ", " rs187607506 ", 
" rs12748266 ", " rs11206510 ", " rs34900073 ", " rs55958021 ", 
" rs12404395 ", " rs11206513 ", " rs7530425 ", " rs11436234 ", 
" rs10888897 ", " rs7543163 ", " rs11206514 ", " rs11206515 ", 
" rs10888898 ", " rs613855 ", " rs624612 ", " rs625619 ", " rs479910"
), c("rs12117661 ", " rs11588151 ", " rs34232196 ", " rs4500361 ", 
" rs4927191 ", " rs200159426 ", " rs187607506 ", " rs12748266 ", 
" rs11206510 ", " rs34900073 ", " rs55958021 ", " rs12404395 ", 
" rs613855 ", " rs624612 ", " rs625619 ", " rs479910 ", " rs568052 ", 
" rs483462 ", " rs615563 ", " rs630431 ", " rs662145 ", " 1:55539780_TA_T ", 
" rs487230 ", " rs683880 ", " rs555687 ", " rs548852"), c("rs12117661 ", 
" rs11588151 ", " rs34232196 ", " rs4500361 ", " rs4927191 ", 
" rs200159426 ", " rs187607506 ", " rs12748266 ", " rs11206510 ", 
" rs34900073 ", " rs55958021 ", " rs12404395 ", " rs613855 ", 
" rs624612 ", " rs625619 ", " rs494198 ", " rs7552841 ", " rs639750 ", 
" rs499883 ", " rs521662 ", " rs1165287 ", " rs634272 ", " rs553741 ", 
" rs693668 ", " rs471705 ", " rs472495 ", " rs479910"), c("rs17111483 ", 
" rs12117661 ", " rs11588151 ", " rs34232196 ", " rs4500361 ", 
" rs4927191 ", " rs200159426 ", " rs199717562 ", " rs200730299 ", 
" rs187607506 ", " rs60228221 ", " rs57498787 ", " rs12141643 ", 
" rs4609471 ", " rs12748266 ", " rs11206510 ", " rs34900073 ", 
" rs55958021 ", " rs12404395 ", " rs28385708 ", " rs613855 ", 
" rs624612 ", " rs625619 ", " rs479910 ", " rs11206517 ", " rs12067569 ", 
" rs10465832 ", " rs56235208 ", " rs72911441")), Belief = c(0.531441, 
0.59049, 0.59049, 0.59049, 0.59049, 0.59049), Plausibility = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Plty Ratio` = c(2.13420294989532, 2.4419428096994, 
2.4419428096994, 2.4419428096994, 2.4419428096994, 2.4419428096994
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Following @akrun's first suggestion `bel_bpa_df %>% unnest(SNPs) %>% mutate(SNPs = trimws(SNPs)) %>% ggplot(aes(SNPs, Belief)) + geom_jitter()`, I got a plot that's pretty dense. I would be so good if I can look at the individual ids in the x-axis. Would plotly do a better job at this?

[image]

Following @Quinten's answer the plot that I got has arbitrary order of labels of SNP names. If have a vector with fixed order of SNP names, can I make a plot with that order specifically?

Comment: Can you show the `dput(yourdata)` as it is not clear about the structure and also dput makes it easier to test

Comment: @akrun the first column are vectors of strings (identifications), the second columns are just numerics.

Comment: If you have a list column, then you may need to unnest it i.e. `df1 %>% unnest(SNPs)` before plotting.  As I mentioned, if you can dput your example, it is easier to test

Comment: @akrun done. The text is too big to be put here completely tho.

Comment: I would get the `dput(head(yourdata))` as broken dput will not work

Comment: @akrun done. This is going to be very clear.

Comment: Try with `df1 %>% unnest(SNPs) %>% mutate(SNPs = trimws(SNPs)) %>% ggplot(aes(SNPs, Belief)) + geom_jitter()`

Comment: Ok I tried what you said and I added the plot with a related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question, you could rotate the x axis labels and change the font size using `theme` and `guides` (you could adjust the font size) like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
bel_bpa_df %>% 
  unnest(SNPs) %>% 
  mutate(SNPs = trimws(SNPs)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(SNPs, Belief)) + 
  geom_jitter() +
  guides(x = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Added a related question.

Comment: Hi @monotonic, I would highly recommend you to ask that as a new question so we can help you better with that.